# Number of substrings in range [l, r] that can be permuted to palindrome

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures

Given a string `s` of lowercase English letters, with `|s| <= 10^5`. There are upto `q <= 10^5` queries giving a range `[l, r]` that asks: how many substrings of the string `s[l...r]` can be permuted to form a palindrome.

Now a string can be permuted to a palindrome iff the number of characters appearing odd number of times is at most `1`. I tried to use a segment tree but can't seem to merge two ranges. How can I approach it?

Comment: In the string `AA`, are there 2 distinct palindromable substrings (`AA` itself, and `A`) or 3 (i.e., do we consider the substring formed from the first `A` distinct from the one formed from the second `A`)?

Comment: Yes they're considered distinct. There are 3 such substrings.

Comment: OK, I just posted an answer that assumes that they aren't...  This answer can be adapted to handle the other case by introducing additional multipliers.

Comment: The query asks for number of palindromable "substrings", not subsequences. Substring is a consecutive portion of a string. For string "abc" the strings "ab", "bc", "abc" are substrings; but "ac" is not.

Comment: Whoops, you're right.  I'll delete it soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For want of a better answer, we can apply Mo's algorithm to get an `O(n^(3/2) |alphabet|)`-time algorithm. That might be fast enough for you. The core is the following incremental algorithm for computing the number of palindromically-permutable substrings of the whole string (in Python 3):

```
import collections


def ppcount(s):
    n = 0
    sigcount = collections.Counter()
    sig = 0
    for c in s:
        sigcount[sig] += 1
        sig ^= 1 << (ord(c) - ord('a'))
        n += sigcount[sig]
        for i in range(26):
            n += sigcount[sig ^ (1 << i)]
    return n
```

The variable `sig` tracks which letters have odd frequency in the input so far. A substring `s[l:r]` (include `l`, exclude `r`) is palindromically-permutable iff the signature for the prefix of length `l` is at Hamming distance at most `1` from the signature for the prefix of length `r-1`.  The map `sigcount` tracks how many prefixes have a particular signature.

To apply Mo's algorithm, first write the inverse operation for the loop body above (i.e., subtract from `n`, update `sig`, and decrement `sigcount`). Read in all of the queries and sort them by `(l // int(sqrt(n)), r)`. For each query in sorted order, use update and inverse update operations to adjust the string being considered to `s[l:r+1]`, then report the current total.

Working Python code (naive version first, for comparison; keep scrolling):

```
import collections
import math
import random


def odd(n):
    return bool(n & 1)


def ispp(s):
    return sum(odd(n) for n in collections.Counter(s).values()) <= 1


def naiveppcount(s):
    n = len(s)
    return sum(ispp(s[l:r + 1]) for l in range(n) for r in range(l, n))


def bit(c):
    return 1 << ((ord(c) - 1) & 31)


def neighbors(sig):
    yield sig
    for i in range(26):
        yield sig ^ (1 << i)


class PPCounter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
        self._sigcount = collections.Counter({0: 1})
        self._leftsig = 0
        self._rightsig = 0

    def pushleft(self, c):
        self._leftsig ^= bit(c)
        for sig in neighbors(self._leftsig):
            self.count += self._sigcount[sig]
        self._sigcount[self._leftsig] += 1

    def popleft(self, c):
        self._sigcount[self._leftsig] -= 1
        for sig in neighbors(self._leftsig):
            self.count -= self._sigcount[sig]
        self._leftsig ^= bit(c)

    def pushright(self, c):
        self._rightsig ^= bit(c)
        for sig in neighbors(self._rightsig):
            self.count += self._sigcount[sig]
        self._sigcount[self._rightsig] += 1

    def popright(self, c):
        self._sigcount[self._rightsig] -= 1
        for sig in neighbors(self._rightsig):
            self.count -= self._sigcount[sig]
        self._rightsig ^= bit(c)


def ppcount(s, intervals):
    sqrtn = int(math.sqrt(len(s)))
    intervals = sorted(
        intervals, key=lambda interval: (interval[0] // sqrtn, interval[1]))
    l = 0
    r = -1
    ctr = PPCounter()
    for interval in intervals:
        il, ir = interval
        while l > il:
            l -= 1
            ctr.pushleft(s[l])
        while r < ir:
            r += 1
            ctr.pushright(s[r])
        while l < il:
            ctr.popleft(s[l])
            l += 1
        while r > ir:
            ctr.popright(s[r])
            r -= 1
        yield interval, ctr.count


def test():
    n = 100
    s = [random.choice('abcd') for i in range(n)]
    intervals = []
    for i in range(1000):
        l = random.randrange(n)
        r = random.randrange(n)
        intervals.append((min(l, r), max(l, r)))
    for (l, r), count in ppcount(s, intervals):
        assert count == naiveppcount(s[l:r + 1])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: I would appreciate it if you would check my linearithmic-time solution for problems.

Comment: The incremental algorithm is one way right? What if I add some characters to the right and then remove/add one from/to the left? Is there any trick to update in O(|alphabet|) in that case?

Comment: @MarkHennings You have to track the signature of the left edge (`lsig`, let's say) in addition to the signature of the right edge (`sig`). The rest is the same.

Comment: Well it doesn't seem so obvious how that can be done. At least to me. To keep track of `lsig` while adding characters to the right takes in worst case linear time. Some hint there?

Comment: @MarkHennings Done.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: *No* solution technique based on recording only the numbers of palindromable substrings beginning, or ending, at each position can work, since it will necessarily fail to distinguish between (at least) the following two cases (found with a computer search), which have identical UpTo[] and From[] arrays, but different sets of PSes:**

```
ijegajaei       dacedcadc
|-------|       |-----|
 |-----|         |-----|
    |-|             |---|
```

**Although the solution attempt I describe below is based on this flawed idea, unless someone has an objection, I think I will leave this information here in case it saves someone else from going down this path.**

---

Here's a different approach that answers each [l, r] query in **O(1) time and online** (that is, we can answer each query as it arrives -- we don't need to see them all and then reorder them) after **O(|A|n log n) preprocessing**, where |A| = 26 is the alphabet size.  It needs O(|A|n) space.

### Overview

The basic idea is to compute in a preprocessing step, for each position i, the number of palindromable substrings ending at i or any earlier position (let's call this UpTo[i]), as well as the number of palindromable substrings beginning at i or any later position (let's call this From[i]).  Once we have this information, notice that for any query [l, r], UpTo[r] + From[l] counts every palindromable substring exactly once, except for palindromable substrings that start at or after l *and* end at or before r, which are counted twice.  So if we subtract the total number of palindromable substrings from the expression UpTo[r] + From[l], we get exactly what we're looking for -- the number of palindromable substrings that start at or after l and end at or before r.  Clearly we can store UpTo[] and From[] in two arrays of length n+1 and perform this calculation in O(1) time per query; the question now is how to calculate the entries in these two tables.

### Suffix-minimal palindromable substrings

First, a few definitions (mostly taken from my earlier, incorrect answer):

Call a range [l, r] *valid* if it is palindromable, i.e., if at most one of the characters in this substring has odd frequency.  Call a valid range *even* if all characters in it have even frequency, otherwise call it *odd*, and in particular *c-odd*, where c is the unique character with odd frequency.

Here we will be concerned with counting the number EndsAt[i] of palindromable substrings (PS) that end at a specific position i.  (Clearly we can compute UpTo[] from the running total of EndsAt[], and we can compute From[] by working with the reversed string.)  We will separately count the number EvenEndsAt[i] of *even* PS that end at i.

Consider an even PS starting at j and ending at i > j.  Either it is the shortest even PS ending at i, in which case we call it *minimal*, or there is some shorter even PS ending at i and starting at some j' > j.  The following observation is key to computing EvenEndsAt[i] efficiently:

- If [j, i] and [j', i] are both even PSes, with j < j' < i, then [j, j'-1] is also an even PS.  (IOW: If a string is an even PS, and it has a proper suffix that is an even PS, then deleting that suffix leaves a string that is also an even PS.)

This follows from the fact that subtracting an even number from an even number always gives an even number.  It means that, if we can determine the minimal even PS [k, i] ending at some i, then we can compute EvenEndsAt[i] using EvenEndsAt[i] = 1 + EvenEndsAt[k-1].

### Finding the minimal even PS ending at i

How to find this minimal even PS [k, i] (when it exists)?  As mentioned in David Eisenstat's answer, in order to determine whether [a, b] is an even PS, all we need to care about is the *parity* (oddness or evenness) of the cumulative character frequencies at position a-1 and position b.  For an even PS, these parities must be equal for each of the 26 letters.  I'll also use *signature* to decribe the set of letters having odd frequency so far.

So what we can do is scan forward through the string, maintaining (in a hashtable or balanced tree) the most recent (i.e., rightmost) location of each signature that we have seen so far.  Note that we *do not* have to record all 2^26 possible signatures -- it suffices to record only those signatures that we have actually seen, which limits space usage to O(n).

### Odd PS

A similar observation holds for odd PSes.  We just need to be careful to count the c-odd PSes ending at each position i separately for each c, so that we don't count any odd PS twice.

Consider an c-odd PS starting at j and ending at i > j.  Either it is the shortest c-odd PS ending at i, in which case we call it *minimal*, or there is some shorter c-odd PS ending at i and starting at some j' > j.  We can compute the total number of c-odd PSes ending at i using the following observation:

- If [j, i] and [j', i] are both c-odd PSes (note: for the same character c!), with j < j' < i, then [j, j'-1] is an *even* PS.  (IOW: If a string is an odd PS, and it has a proper suffix that is an odd PS and in which the same character has odd frequency, then deleting that suffix leaves a string that is an even PS.)

The reasoning is only slightly harder than last time: If we have an odd number and some even numbers, and we subtract an odd number from the odd number and (possibly different) even numbers from each even number, we must wind up with only even numbers.  Thus if [k, i] is the minimal c-odd PS ending at position i, then the total number of c-odd PSes ending at position i is given by 1 + EvenEndsAt[k-1].

### Pseudocode

Here is pseudocode for computing the UpTo[] table.  As mentioned previously, From[] can be computed by running this on the reversed string, and then each query can be answered in O(1) time (either UpTo[n] or From[1] will give the total number of PSes in the entire string, which is needed for the final subtraction).  I use 1-based indices here:

```
FindPS():
    Dictionary lastPosOfSignature       # Hashtable or balanced tree
    currentSig = 0                      # Integer used as 26-bit bitset
    For i from 1 to n:
        # Find the minimal even PS ending at i, if it exists
        currentSig ^= 1 << (S[i] - 'a')
        If lastPosOfSignature contains currentSig:
            # There's a minimal even PS ending at i.
            k = lastPosOfSignature{currentSig}
            EvenEndsAt[i] = 1
            If k > 1:
                EvenEndsAt[i] += EvenEndsAt[k-1]
        Else:
            EvenEndsAt[i] = 0

        EndsAt[i] = 0
        For c from 1 to 26:
            # Find the minimal c-odd PS ending at i, if it exists
            cOddSig = currentSig ^ (1 << (c-1))
            If lastPosOfSignature contains cOddSig:
                # There's a minimal c-odd PS ending at i.
                k = lastPosOfSignature{cOddSig}
                EndsAt[i] += 1
                If k > 1:
                    EndsAt[i] += EvenEndsAt[k-1]

        lastPosOfSignature{currentSig} = i
        UpTo[i] = EndsAt[i]
        If i > 1:
            UpTo[i] += UpTo[i-1]
```

Comment: Doesn't the total number of palindromable substrings include substrings that begin before `l` and end after `r`?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: You're right!  Do you think there's an easy way around this, or is it fundamental?

Comment: I would be surprised if there were an easy way around this -- the correlation between the two tests (ends after `r`) and (starts before `l`) strikes me as a free variable.